# Cache eloquent model with all of it's relations then convert it back to model with relations?

Tags: laravel, caching, eloquent, casting

I am trying to optimize a project that is working pretty slow using caching. I'm facing a problem that I don't quite understand how to cache full eloquent models with their relationships and later on covert them back to a model with all relations intact. Here's a fragment of my code

```
if (Cache::has($website->id.'_main_page')) {
        $properties = (array) json_decode(Cache::get($website->id.'_main_page'));
        $page = Page::hydrate($properties);
      }else{
        $expiresAt = now()->addMinutes(60);
        $page = Page::with(['sections', 'pageSections.sectionObjects'])->where('website_id', $website->id)->where('main', 1)->first();
        Cache::put($website->id.'_main_page', $page->toJson(), $expiresAt);
      }
```

Problem is, `hydrate` seems to be casting this data as a collection when in fact it's suppose to be a single model. And thus later on I am unable to access any of it's properties without getting errors that they don't exists. `$properties` variable looks perfect and I would use that but I need laravel to understand it as a Page model instead of stdClass, I also need all of the relationships to be cast into their appropriate models. Is this even possible? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't use the cache like this

```
$page = Cache::remember($website->id.'_main_page', 60 * 60, function () use ($website) {
    return Page::with(['sections', 'pageSections.sectionObjects'])
         ->where('website_id', $website->id)
         ->where('main', 1)
         ->first();
});
```

Conditional

```
$query = Page::query();
$key = $website->id.'_main_page';

if (true) {
    $query = $query->where('condition', true);
    $key = $key . '_condition_true';
}

$query::with(['sections', 'pageSections.sectionObjects'])
         ->where('main', 1)

$page = Cache::remember($key, 60 * 60, function () use ($query) {
    return $query->first();
});
```

Comment: I'm quite green with Laravel's cache and didn't even know about the existence of "remember" this seems to do the trick! Thank you very much for this elegant solution. Just one note - I had to change it to function() uses($website), otherwise it's scope couldn't access the $website variable

Comment: @Matrix One thing to notice, that has tripped me up a few times, is that the time (60 * 60) is in minutes, and not seconds, how long the cache should save the results for that key. Remember to accept the answer so other people can find the help too in the future :)

Comment: Oh so 60*60 would actually store it for 60 hours?

Comment: @Matrix Sorry, it threw me off again! I meant the parameter is in seconds, so I did 60 (seconds) * 60 to get it to 60 minutes, as your code showed. My bad :)

Comment: One more question, how would I use Cache::remember with a query builder that spans for a bunch of lines and is conditional?

Comment: @Matrix I have updated the question with an example :) Pseudocode, but the trick is to build a key along with the query and then cache the query with a key that represents the conditional.